# Laravel not sending email or not received mail

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I am trying to send a mail from my domain email (cPanel), but I didn't receive any mail in my Gmail Account. Also, Laravel didn't display any errors.

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Also, I add `implements MustVerifyEmail` to the `User` model class.

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendUserEmailVerification;

Route::get('/send-email', function () {
    Mail::to("myaccount@gmail.com")->send(new SendUserEmailVerification());
    return response("success");
});
```

**SendUserEmailVerification.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendUserEmailVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.user.email_verfy');
    }
}
```

**email_verfy.blade.php**

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

When I use `mailtrap.io`, it shows mail in the inbox.

Also, it's working on using `PHPMailer` as https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer but it seems a little bit hard to manage email verification on Laravel.

**Why I didn't get the mail that Laravel send?**

**Does anybody know something?**

Please guide me.

Comment: any errors while sending email

Comment: add try catch to mail::to and see what you get any exception

Comment: try one and lets see what you get in mail exception .it will be same error i think.also dont forget to check gmail spam folder

Comment: check spam folder in gmail

Answer (score 0):

**.ENV**

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your-gmail-username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your-application-specific-password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Send it with the `Mail::raw()` function:

```php
\Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html');
});
```

Other option is using the `Mail::send()` function:

```php
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to('my@email.com')
    ->subject('my subject')
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!'); 
});
```

Hope this works for you, please let me know!

*Previous answer before edit after [Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo)'s comment*:

> What exactly is going wrong? Do you not want to receive your mail on [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/signin) but Gmail instead?

Comment: My apologies, I understand.
I have edited my answer above, hope this helps @JSTECH.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. You wanted to send your mail to a Gmail address right? I've posted two options to do so in my answer. Did you test this?
Did you read the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#mail-and-local-development) on testing and pretend?